# Link google map to zip code in textview

Tags: android, google-maps

I have divided my screen into two linear layouts. In the first layout I load the google map with custom markers on it. In the second one I have the address in the format

```
New York, NY-20202
Aberdeen, MD-21022
```

How can i link these zip codes to the google map that I am loading in the first view. I already have these markers on the map. When a user clicks on any zip code the google map should be zoomed to that marker. I have tried linkify but it does not link until and unless i have the full address. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

- Store the latlng of all the addresses from which you are extracting those zipcodes against the zipcode string (eg: New York, NY-20202) as keys which you will display in (assuming these strings are unique for every location you are storing).

For instance, it can look something like this:

```
Map<String, LatLng> zipToLocationMap = new HashMap<>();

zipToLocationMap.put(YOURZIPSTRING, new LatLng(lat, lng));
```

- Make textviews clickable when adding them to listview or layout and add an OnClickListener. Then inside onClick method, get the text of textview and get the LatLng object stored against that textview from zipToLocationMap.

After getting the LatLng object, zoom into the map to using that latlng coordinates.

```
zipTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            latLng location = hashMap.get(zipTextView.getText());
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 2.5f)); 
            //first param is latlng object and second is zoom factor
        }
    });
```

Comment: it works as expected. Thanks so much for the solution. Just a follow up solution. Would you have an idea of how to implement a search functionality in google map.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget

Comment: You can use PlacesComplete widget or implement custom AutoCompletePredictions to get search results for places and when you select a location from a prediction, just use that object to get its latlng and use map.animateCamera method to zoom into that location